# R-stack layout graphs in Quarto

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, reveal.js, quarto

I would like to use the [`r-stack`](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html) layout class in a `Quarto` presentation with ggplot and ggplotly output. For images we could use the following code like shown in the link above:

```
---
title: "r-stack with graphs in Quarto"
format: revealjs
---

## Example slide

::: {.r-stack}
![](image1.png){.fragment width="450" height="300"}

![](image2.png){.fragment width="300" height="450"}

![](image3.png){.fragment width="400" height="400"}
:::
```

Using the following code with `r-stack` class doesn't work:

````
---
title: "r-stack with graphs in Quarto"
format: revealjs
---

## Example slide

::: {.r-stack}

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point()
ggplotly(p1)
```

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point()
ggplotly(p2)
```

:::
````

Output:

[image]

Nothing happens. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to use the `r-stack` class with ggplotly graphs like it is possible with the images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html#stack-layout) `.r-stack`

> is intended to be used together with **fragments** to incrementally reveal elements.

Hence, to make `.r-stack` work you have wrap your plots in `fragements`.

Note: I used different widths and heights to make the stacking of the plots visible.

````
---
title: "r-stack with graphs in Quarto"
format: revealjs
---

## Example slide

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
```

::: {.r-stack}

::: {.fragment}
```{r fig.width=4, fig.height=5}
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point()
ggplotly(p1)
```
:::

::: {.fragment}
```{r fig.width=5, fig.height=4}
p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point()
ggplotly(p2)
```
:::

:::
````

[image]